# SQL Server 2008, concatenating Strings?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, concatenation

I have wasted my 2 whole days to trying to resolve this issue, Now I am going out of my mind, I need an urgent Help,
The Issue is,
I Have To Tables

Table: Sales, *SalesId* is `primary key`

```
---------------------------------------------------
SalesId | SalesDate | Customer| Discount | Remarks
---------------------------------------------------
1       | 01/01/2012|   John  |   15     |   NULL
2       | 01/01/2012|   Peter |   25     |   NULL
3       | 01/01/2012| Micheal |   35     |   NULL
```

Table: SalesBody, *SerialNo* is `primary key` and *SalesId* is `foreign key`

```
---------------------------------------------------
SerialNo | SalesId | Product | Quantity | Rate
---------------------------------------------------
10       | 1       | Pencil   | 18       | 20
11       | 1       | pen      | 200      | 60
12       | 1       | Rubber   | 150      | 10
13       | 1       | Paper    | 500      | 2
14       | 2       | Mouse    | 15       | 190
15       | 2       | KeyBoard | 10       | 600
16       | 2       | Monitor  | 5        | 2000
17       | 3       | Mobile   | 2        | 15000
```

Now I want to make a query which can make the result like following

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SalesId | SalesDate  | Details                               | Amount
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 01/01/2012 | Sold: Pencil x 18 @ 20, Pen x 200 @ 60| xxxxxxx
        |            |  Rubber x 150 @ 10, Paper x 500 @ 2   |
2       | 01/01/2012 | Sold: Mouse x 15 @ 190, Keyboard x 10 |
        |            |  @ 600, Monitor x 5 @ 2000            | xxxxxxx
3       | 01/01/2012 | Sold: Mobile x 2 @ 15000              | xxxxxxx
```

I have tried different techniques eg. Coalesce, Stuff, For XML PATH('')

I could not Concatenate the Detail String.

Comment: AFAIK aggregate concatenation [is not trivial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server) in SQL server

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT do same in MySQL, you can search alternative in SQL server.. http://explainextended.com/2010/06/21/group_concat-in-sql-server/

Comment: why are you trying to do that in SQL ? client side languages are way better for this scenario

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can see you just need to pivot the SalesBody table and group by SalesID

Something along the lines of the below query should do the trick

```
select sb.SalesId, ( SELECT ', ' + sb2.Product + ' x ' + sb2.Quantity + ' @ ' + sb2.Rate
       FROM SalesBody sb2
       WHERE sb2.SalesId = sb.SalesId 
       FOR XML PATH('') ) AS Details
from SalesBody sb
group by sb.SalesId
```

Then just join that query with your Sales table to get the other data and do a STUFF command on Details in the query above to remove the leading "," and add your "sold: " string and you should be all good to go.

Comment: Nice. To replace the leading `,` with `Sold:`, something like `STUFF((SELECT ...), 1, 1, 'Sold:')` could do.